# Scanner Class to create tokens of an input file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, stringtokenizer

I have written the following code in java to open another `.java` file and create tokens (using scanner class)

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scanner1 {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception
    {
        FileReader fin = new FileReader("mysourcefile.java");
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(fin);
        scan.useDelimiter(" ");   // the delimiter pattern required
        while(scan.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(scan.next());
        }
    }
}
```

My task is to create the tokens of complete `Java` file and the delimiters should be treated as the tokens also.

So what should be the delimiter pattern to use here in `scan.useDelimiter("")`?

**UPDATE:**

The above task was completed using the stringtokenizer. But I don't know the exact pattern of the delimiter to create tokens for a `.java` file. Can I have an answer about what the delimiter pattern to use in the given case ?

```
import java.util.*;
public class sstring2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "a=(b+c); String st='hello! my dear';";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, "[ =+';().*{}[],!@#$%^&/]", true);
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(st.nextToken());
        }
    }
}
```

This code gives the correct results.

Comment: Note: you can chain: `new Scanner(fin).useDelimiter("whatever")`. `.useDelimiter()` returns `this`.

Comment: Hm, this is what you should read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/. Assuming you're trying to build a serious Java source code parser.

Comment: Scanner is designed to ignore delimiters. StringTokenizer may be a better choice.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes i have used the stringtokenizer as well. it gives the delimiters correctly. but delimiter string issue is the same there i am facing. i may edit and post that java code as well

Comment: "my task is to create the tokens of complete java file and the delimiters should be treated as the tokens also." - I still didn't get the question. As in a java file can have anything literally. So, do you first even validate if it's a proper java file? And after tokenizing what are you going to do? Are you trying to build a custom home made compiler?

Comment: @Arham it is assumed that the file is valid. i have to modify the contents of the methods. i have to add some lines in a particular method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the java.lang.instrument packagae. It provides some nice APIs to transform an already loaded class. The retransformation allows to change method bodies as in your case. Here's the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/instrumentation/changes6.html)

Answer (score 1):

it may be any character on which you want to terminate the input.

Comment: what character(s) to be used for complete .java file to be tokenized ?